# Having an issue with using median function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, split, median

I am having an issue with using the median function in numpy.  The code used to work on a previous computer but when I tried to run it on my new machine, I got the error "cannot perform reduce with flexible type".  In order to try to fix this, I attempted to use the map() function to make sure my list was a floating point and got this error message: could not convert string to float: .

Do some more attempts at debugging, it seems that my issue is with my splitting of the lines in my input file.  The lines are of the form: 2456893.248202,4.490   and I want to split on the ",".  However, when I print out the list for the second column of that line, I get
4
.
4
9
0

so it seems to somehow be splitting each character or something though I'm not sure how.  The relevant section of code is below, I appreciate any thoughts or ideas and thanks in advance.

```
def curve_split(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            time,lc = line.split(",")
#debugging stuff 
            g=open('test.txt','w')
            l1=map(lambda x:x+'\n',lc)
            g.writelines(l1)
            g.close()
#end debugging stuff

            return time,lc



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # place where I keep the lightcurve files from the image subtraction
    dirname = '/home/kuehn/m4/kepler/subtraction/detrending'
    files = glob.glob(dirname + '/*lc')
    print(len(files))



# in order to create our lightcurve array, we need to know
# the length of one of our lightcurve files

lc0 = curve_split(files[0])

lcarr = np.zeros([len(files),len(lc0)])

    # loop through every file
for i,fn in enumerate(files):
        time,lc = curve_split(fn)
        lc = map(float, lc)

# debugging
        print(fn[5:58])
        print(lc)
        print(time)
# end debugging

        lcm = lc/np.median(float(lc))
        #lcm = ((lc[qual0]-np.median(lc[qual0]))/
        #    np.median(lc[qual0]))
        lcarr[i] = lcm
        print(fn,i,len(files))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here. This is hardly a minimal example.  You seem to have a problem with string functions, rather than with median.

Please provide a minimal example in reproducible form.  Include your input data.

Comment: What @Prune said: Your issue looks like it might be related to character encoding ("ANSI" vs. Unicode), or perhaps different versions of Python, or maybe something else fairly fundamental. Whatever it is, you need to get it sorted out before you can expect to do anything useful with NumPy, so all the NumPy details are just getting in the way. Please [edit] your question to focus on what the real issue is.